# Can a table have a value associated to IT?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Kind of like a static variable in an analogy to classes.

For example, lets say i have a table for keeping people. Then for each row I have a bunch of columns: age, sex, name...
But I would like a value to be associated to the table itself, lets say, `minimum allowed age = 18`. Then, whenever I would add a new person I would check if their age is bigger than `Table.minimum_allowed_age`. This way I could easely change that value, without beign hard coded anywhere.

The only way I can do it now is by creating a (very ugly) ENUM column that has only one option, `18`, and then every row has it. This is obviously not the way to do it, especially if you want to change that value often (which is my case in my application).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, a static variable is shared between object instances, but there's only one instance of the table anyway...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are technically globals. How about using another table to store global properties?

A string for the primary key, another string that is `CAST` to an integer in a nested query fetching the value would work.

You might as well use an integer value if sufficient or several, differently-typed maybe-`NULL` columns if you want type safety (you may `COALESCE` and `CAST` the result to a string for a fully generic string->string view).

For globals that are associated with tables you could establish an appropriate convention, e.g. prefixing the key with the table name and some separator.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Some database servers let you attach a few bits of metadata to a table (e.g, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in MySQL, or the `COMMENT` field in various SQL databases), but they are not suitable for general-purpose data storage.

In your case, the value that you're describing (minimum allowed age) isn't a property of the table at all -- it's a property of your *application logic*. If it's going to be constant over the long term, write it as a constant in your code; if it will be changed more often, create a separate table which stores configuration key/value pairs for the whole application.

Comment: How do you think I should deal with my situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing insert triggers. Inside the trigger code,you can check if the minimum age is 18 and if not, you can set it to 18.